# Linear Operators and Mapping

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, linear-transformations

I have been working through a worksheet on linear algebra and came across this question on linear operators that puzzled me.

The question describes a linear operator $T$ on $R^3$, that maps $\mathbf v_1 = (1, -3, -4)$ to $\mathbf v_2 = (2, 7, -8)$ and maps $\mathbf v_3 = (-2, 5, 0)$ to $\mathbf v_4 = (-1, 1, -12)$

It then asks two things.

1. Does the above information uniquely determine $T(\mathbf v_2)$?
   If so, find it.
2. Does the above information uniquely determine $T(\mathbf v_4)$? If so, find it.

What is the best way to answer and reason these two questions? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

*My initial approach:*

I tried thinking about this question as a matrix equation using 3 3x3 matrices: $A$, $X$ and $Y$ - where is A is the matrix form of transformation $T$, $X$ is the "input" matrix formed by column vectors $\mathbf v_1$, $\mathbf v_2$ and $\mathbf v_3$, and $Y$ is the "output" matrix formed by column vectors $\mathbf v_2$, $T(\mathbf v_2)$ and $\mathbf v_4$.

My approach was that built around the equation $AX = Y$ - which I thought resembled the transformation $T$ being applied to $X$ to produce $Y$. By inverting matrix $X$ and finding the product of it with matrix $Y$, we could find $A$ and thus would help us find $T(\mathbf v_4)$. But this hinges on knowing $T(\mathbf v_2)$ - which is unknown.

Therefore I concluded that the answer to 1) was "no" and the answer to 2) was also "no". I was a little confused on the meaning of "uniquely determine" so there was the possibility of "yes" for 2), but I was unsure.

Comment: $v_4=3v_1+2v_3$ so the answer to 2) is yes.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @geetha290krm thank you for your response! With your equation, are you saying that we can use the results for $T(\mathbf v_1)$ and $T(\mathbf v_3)$ to help directly find $T(\mathbf v_4)$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos thank you for response, I have added my initial thoughts and approach to the question in an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That information uniquely determines $T(\mathbf v_4)$, since $\mathbf v_4=3\mathbf v_1+2\mathbf v_3$, and therefore$$T(\mathbf v_4)=3T(\mathbf v_1)+2T(\mathbf v_3)=(4,23,-48).$$

However, it doesn't determine uniquely $T(\mathbf v_2)$. Note that $\mathbf v_2$ is not a linear combination of $\mathbf v_1$ and $\mathbf v_3$. It turns out that, if you consider the linear maps$$T_1(x,y,z)=\frac1{20}(-4y-7z,4y-38z,-48y+76z)$$and$$T_2(x,y,z)=\frac1{10}(10x+2y-4z,2y-19z,-24y+38z),$$then both of them map $\mathbf v_1$ into $\mathbf v_2$ and $\mathbf v_3$ into $\mathbf v_4$. However, they are distinct maps.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I did know before that the transformations of a single vector can apply to its linear combination vectors too.